# sql select number divided aggregate sum function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this schema

[image]

and I want to have a query to calculate the cost per consultant per hour per month. In other words, a consultant has a salary per month, I want to divide the amount of the salary between the hours that he/she worked that month.

```
SELECT
    concat_ws(' ', consultants.first_name::text, consultants.last_name::text) as name,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tasks.init_time) as task_month,
    SUM(tasks.finish_time::timestamp::time - tasks.init_time::timestamp::time) as duration,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM salaries.payment_date) as salary_month,
    salaries.payment
FROM consultants
INNER JOIN tasks ON consultants.id = tasks.consultant_id
INNER JOIN salaries ON consultants.id = salaries.consultant_id
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tasks.init_time) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM salaries.payment_date)
GROUP BY (consultants.id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tasks.init_time), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM salaries.payment_date), salaries.payment);
```

It is not possible to do this in the select

```
salaries.payment / SUM(tasks.finish_time::timestamp::time - tasks.init_time::timestamp::time)
```

Is there another way to do it? Is it possible to solve it in one query?

Comment: Added `postgresql` tag based on the `::` casts

Comment: What data type is `tasks.finish_time`? The duplicate cast seems odd. Casting to `time` also means that the difference won't be correct if the interval between init_time and finish_time spans more than one day (e.g. from 21:00 to 07:00)

Comment: Do you have one row for each day when a consultant got paid? What exactly does `salaries.date` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumptions made for this answer:

The model is not entirely clear to me, so I am assuming the following:

- you are using PostgreSQL
- `salaries.date` is defined as a `date` column that stores the day when a consultant was paid
- `tasks.init_time` and `task.finish_time` are defined as `timestamp` storing the data & time when a consultant started and finished work on a specific task.

---

Your join on **only** the month is wrong as far as I can tell. For one, because it would also include months from different years, but more importantly because this would lead to a result where the same row from `salaries` appeared several times. I *think* you need to join on the complete date:

```
FROM consultants c 
  JOIN tasks t ON c.id = t.consultant_id
  JOIN salaries s ON c.id = s.consultant_id 
                 AND t.init_time::date = s.payment_date --<< here
```

If my assumptions about the data types are correct, the cast to a `timestamp` and then back to a `time` is useless and wrong. Useless because you can simply subtract to timestamps and wrong because you are ignoring the actual date in the timestamp so (although unlikely) if `init_time` and `finish_time` are not on the same day, the result is wrong.

So the calculation of the duration can be simplified to:

```
t.finish_time - t.init_time
```

To get the cost per hour per month, you need to convert the `interval` (which is the result when subtracting one timestamp from another) to a decimal indicating the hours, you can do this by extracting the seconds from the interval and then dividing that by 3600, e.g.

```
extract(epoch from sum(t.finish_time - t.init_time)) / 3600)
```

If you divide the sum of the payments by that number you get your cost per hour per month:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', c.first_name, c.last_name) as name,
       to_char(s.payment_date, 'yyyy-mm') as salary_month,
       extract(epoch from sum(t.finish_time - t.init_time)) / 3600 as worked_hours, 
       sum(s.payment) / (extract(epoch from sum(t.finish_time - t.init_time)) / 3600) as cost_per_hour
FROM consultants c 
  JOIN tasks t ON c.id = t.consultant_id
  JOIN salaries s ON c.id = s.consultant_id AND t.init_time::date = s.payment_date
GROUP BY c.id, to_char(s.payment_date, 'yyyy-mm') --<< no parentheses!
order by name, salary_month;
```

As you want the report broken down by month you should convert the month into something that contains the year as well. I used `to_char()` to get a string with only year and month. You also need to remove `salaries.payment` from the `group by` clause.

You also don't need the "payment month" and "salary month" because both will always be the same as that is the join condition.

And finally you don't need the cast to `::text` for the name columns because they are most certainly defined as `varchar` or `text` anyway.

The sample data I made up for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae0c9

---

Somewhat unrelated, but:
You should also **not** put the column list of the group by in parentheses. Putting a column list in parentheses in Postgres creates an anonymous record which is something completely different then having multiple columns. This is also true for the columns in the select list.

Comment: Thank you very much @a_horse_with_no_name, brilliant answer. The asumptions were right. I did not realize that the database was needed, I thought that this query could be done with ANSI SQL, but the type date and timestamp does not allow that. Also you were right about my mistakes in the query. Thank you for the sqlfiddle, fiddles are always very useful. Lastly, thank you also for the last comment about the parentheses. The only thing is I thing that this part `AND t.init_time::date = s.payment_date` is needless and breaking the query.

Comment: @agusgambina: the `AND t.init_time::date = s.payment_date` condition only uses the `date` part of `init_time` and assumes that `payment_date` is a `date`. If you don't cast `init_time` to a date you would never have a match (because of the time part in a timestamp that does down to milliseconds)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, the explanation was perfect. For the purpose I need the query, I just change it a little bit, I erase it `AND t.init_time::date = s.payment_date` in the inner join. Then in the select I change `SUM(s.payment)...` for `s.payment...` was a previous mistake of mine. Lastly I have to add `s.payment` to the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If at all the target is putting it in one query, then just confirming, have you tried to achieve it using CTEs?
Like

```
    ;WITH cte_pymt
    AS
    (
    //Your existing query 1
    )
    SELECT <your required data> FROM cte_pymt
```